# Clarification/Elaboration of a solution to proving a inclusion map is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

So I was looking at solutions to a homework problem, but I don't understand the solution entirely.

The problem goes as follows:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $ E \subset X$ a subset with the induced metric (for $x_1,x_2 \in E$, $d_E(x_1,x_2) = d_X(x_1,x_2)$. Show that the inclusion map $i: E \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Solution:

> Given $ \varepsilon >0$ choose $\delta= \varepsilon$ to conclude that if $d_E(x_1,x_2) < \delta$, then $d_X(i(x_1),i(x_2))= d_E(x_1,x_2) < \varepsilon.$ So $i$ is continuous.

What is being said here is that once we are given an $\varepsilon$, we immediately set our $\delta$ to $\varepsilon$.
How does one know this a priori? How does one know from the get-go that we should set $\delta$ to equal to $\varepsilon$? Because usually what you do to find such a $\delta$ is you work your way from $d_X(i(x_1),i(x_2)) < \epsilon$ until you get to or deduce something of the form $d_E(x_1,x_2) < \delta$.  Whatever $\delta$ that it is that ends up in the inequality, that is your necessary $\delta$ that would satisfy  $d_X(i(x_1),i(x_2)) < \epsilon$. But here in the solution it is chosen from the start. The solution is not very convincing to me. Could someone elaborate on the though process behind the solution. Is that $\delta$ chosen because we know before hand that the metrics are the same? I can't tell if this is something very trivial or extremely subtle. Clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way one writes a proof need not be in the same order as the thought process that led to the construction of the proof.

Note that any proof where you "do some work to find the form of $\delta$" can just as well be written by immediately declaring what $\delta$ should be at the beginning, and then checking that it works. Although it seems deceiving because you are hiding the thought process that led you to find this $\delta$ and making it seem like you are pulling this $\delta$ from thin air, it does not make the proof any less valid.

You could rewrite the proof in your post by following the thought process that you are comfortable with, and it would be essentially the same as the provided proof.

Comment: I made an attempt at writing the proof (I'm not even sure if it's correct, and I'm not convinced of my own proof, but it was all I had): Suppose $i: E \rightarrow X$ is continuous. Then given $\varepsilon > 0$, there will exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_E(x_1,x_2) < \delta \implies d_X(i(x_1),i(x_2)) < \varepsilon$ holds. Let $\delta = \varepsilon$. It follows that if $d_E(x_1,x_2) < \delta$, then $d_X(i(x_1),i(x_2)) = d_X(x_1,x_2) = d_E(x_1,x_2) < \varepsilon = \delta$. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: The reason I am not convinced of these proofs is because they feel/seem vacuously true.

Comment: I don’t think I conveyed this correctly. What is the thought process that goes into go constructing such a proof. So many logical steps one could make, how does one know which to take, or sometimes it’s what if any logical step can you make if you don’t know any. I don’t think I know enough about proofs, is there a resource on here that you think is especially enlightening about how to think about constructing proofs?